# Disable arrow keys while modal open using document.removeEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

I made a game with HTML canvas in which the user can control the movement of a character.

Links: [live website](https://nataliecardot.com/arcade-game/index.html)/[GitHub repo](https://github.com/nataliecardot/arcade-game)

My goal is to disable arrow keys while the modal that displays when the game is over is open. I tried this by adding the following to the `showModal()` function, which is the same as the version of the event listener that is added at the end of the JavaScript (then I would re-add this event listener when the game is reset). It doesn't do anything, though.

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
  };

  player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});
```

Full JS code from this file (there are two other JS files but I don't think they're relevant):

```
"use strict"; // Enables strict mode to catch common bloopers

// TODO: Disable player movement when modal opened? Also, set 3 tries before modal opened (change to game over). Restart button.

// TODO: Start game on enter when modal opened

const playAgainButton = document.querySelector('.play-again');
const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart');

// Calls playAgain() function when user clicks reset icon in sidebar
restartButton.addEventListener('click', playAgain);

// Starts lives at 3
let lives = 3;

let sidebarLives = document.querySelector('.lives-left');
sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;

// Sets an initial player score of 0.
let score = 0;
// Sets score shown in sidebar
// document.getElementsByClassName('score')[0].innerHTML = score;
let sidebarScore = document.querySelector('.score');
sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;

let modalScore = document.querySelector('.modal-score');
modalScore.innerHTML = score;

// Called when user clicks restart button in sidebar or play again button in modal. Sets modal to display: none, resets lives and score
function playAgain() {
  // Hides modal if present (if opened by game ending)
  modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
  lives = 3;
  sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;
  score = 0;
  sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;
}

// Calls playAgain() function (hides modal and restarts game) with user clicks "play again" button in modal
// TODO: remove? just one event listener for both buttons?
// modalPlayAgainButton.addEventListener('click', playAgain);

// Note: In a constructor function "this" does not have a value. It is a substitute for the new object. The value of this will become the new object when a new object is created

// Note commas not used to separate methods and properties in a class
class Player {
  // Constructor function, a special function just for initializing new objects, will automatically run when a new object is constructed (with keyword "new") from this class. Contains data needed to create it
  constructor(x, y, speed) {
    this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  // Methods that all objects created from class will inherit. Would exist on prototype in pre-class way of writing it, but effect is the same (the following methods still exist on Player prototype [for example would be Player.prototype.update = function(dt)...])

  // When player reaches water, moves player back to starting position, and increase score by 1
  update(dt) {
    if (this.y === 25) {
      this.x = 200;
      this.y = 400;
      score++;
      sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;
    }
  }

  // Draws player on screen
  render() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y)
  }

  // Connects keyboard input to player movement. If statements prevent player movement off screen
  handleInput(allowedKeys) {

    if (allowedKeys === 'down' && this.y < 425) {
      this.y += 25;
    }

        if (allowedKeys === 'up') {
            this.y -= 25;
        }

        if (allowedKeys === 'left' && this.x > 0) {
            this.x -= 25;
        }

        if (allowedKeys === 'right' && this.x < 400) {
            this.x += 25;
        }
  }
}

class Enemy {
// Sets enemy's initial location
  constructor(x, y, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // Sets speed of enemy
    this.speed = speed;
    // The image/sprite for our enemies
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
  }

  update(dt) {
    // Multiplies enemy's movement by time delta to ensure game runs at same speed for all computers
    this.x += this.speed * dt;
    // Once enemy finished moving across screen, moves it back so it can cross screen again and randomizes its speed
    if (this.x > 500) {
      this.x = -75;
      // Math.random() function returns random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Math.floor() returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number
      this.speed = 70 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 450);
    }

    // When collission occurs, subtracts a life, updates lives displayed in sidebar and updates score that will be displayed in modal if no lives remaining
    if ((player.x < (this.x + 70)) && ((player.x + 17) > this.x) && (player.y < (this.y + 45)) && ((30 + player.y) > this.y)) {
        player.x = 200;
        player.y = 400;
      lives--;
      sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;
      modalScore.innerHTML = score;
      if (lives === 0) {
        // Calls function that adds class that sets modal to display: block
        showModal();
      }
    }
  }

  // Draws enemy on the screen
  render() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
  }
};


// ENEMY/PLAYER OBJECT INSTANTIATION

let enemyPosition = [60, 140, 220];

let allEnemies = [];

let player = new Player(200, 400, 50);

enemyPosition.forEach(function(posY) {
  let enemy = new Enemy(0, posY, 70 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 450));
  allEnemies.push(enemy);
});

// Modal

const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const closeIcon = document.querySelector('.close');

// When called, adds class that sets modal to display: block when player reaches water
function showModal() {
  modal.classList.add('modal-visible');

  // Goal: Disable arrow keys while the modal is open (doesn't work). If I can get this to work, then I'd re-add the arrow key event listener when the game is reset
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    let allowedKeys = {
      37: 'left',
      38: 'up',
      39: 'right',
      40: 'down'
    };
    // Not sure why "player" needs to be lowercase, given the class name is uppercase
    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
  });

  // Calls playAgain() function when user clicks play again button in modal
  playAgainButton.addEventListener('click', playAgain);

  // If esc is pressed, closes modal and restarts game (note: keydown used instead of keypress because keypress only works for keys that produce a character value)
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 27) {
      modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
      playAgain()
    }
  });

  // If enter is pressed, closes modal and restarts game
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
      playAgain()
    }
  });

  // If user clicks modal's close icon, closes modal and restarts game
  closeIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
    playAgain();
  });
}


// Listens for keydown event (fired when a key is pressed down [regardless of whether it produces a character, unlike keypress]) and sends the keys to Player.handleInput() method
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
  };
  // Not sure why "player" needs to be lowercase, given the class name is uppercase
  player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing and/or filtering out the specific key events, when the game state changes *(e.g.: when the character dies)*, for starters, as a simpler solution, **use a flag** *(a boolean value)* to indicate, whether your character should be moving or not.

```
let isDead = false;
```

When your character dies, **set the flag** to `false`:

```
if (lives === 0) {
  isDead = true;
  // Calls function that adds class that sets modal to display: block
  showModal();
}
```

And in your input handling function, **use the flag** to allow/disallow the character movement:

```
// Connects keyboard input to player movement. If statements prevent player movement off screen
handleInput(allowedKeys) {
  if (isDead) {
    return;
  }

  if (allowedKeys === 'down' && this.y < 425) {
    this.y += 25;
  }

  if (allowedKeys === 'up') {
    this.y -= 25;
  }

  if (allowedKeys === 'left' && this.x > 0) {
    this.x -= 25;
  }

  if (allowedKeys === 'right' && this.x < 400) {
    this.x += 25;
  }
}
```

Or just outright avoid calling the `handleInput(...)` function in the event handler:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
  };

  // notice that we only want to call the handleInput function
  // when the player is alive, hence !isDead
  if (!isDead) {
    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
  } 
});
```

And when you restart the game, **set the flag** to its default value:

```
function playAgain() {
  modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
  isDead = false;
  lives = 3;
  sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;
  score = 0;
  sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;
}
```

---

## Note

**Since you're developing a game, even when it's just a simple game, I strongly recommend you to manage your game behavior using [game states](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13244/game-state-management-techniques).**

Answer (score 0):

you can try a few different approaches to a problem if one does not work.
Say you have a Boolean variable that is true when the modal is open and false when it is closed. this would work

```
keyCode = modalIsOpen || e.keyCode
```

if the modal is open the keycode would be set as true rather than a number.
this way is unorthodox but it works.